# Testing Effect of Network Connection Drop in The Middle Of Program

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I want to test effect of network connection drop exactly before the execution of specific line of a program. Such as consider this execution sequence:

```
1. Connect to database.
2. Get country list from database.
3. Get a random country from list.
4. Get city list of this country from database.
```

I want to test behavior of program if network connection drops just before statement 4. I'm able test it with debugger by putting a break point, closing database when it hits break point, and then continuing to run program.

I wonder how can I accomplish this in a more systematic and robust way.

Comment: Maybe you can use an aspect or something like that in a test to trigger on whatever method corresponds to step 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make the assumption that the 4 lines of pseudo code are in MyService, and that MyService uses MyDAO to access the database, you would have the following:

```
public class MyService {

    private MyDAO myDAO;

    public MySErvice(MyDAO myDAO) {
        this.myDAO = myDAO;
    }

    public List<City> getRandomCityList() {
        List<Country> countries = myDAO.getCountries();
        Country c = pickRandom(countries);
        return myDAO.getCities(country);
    }
}
```

To test it, use a mocking framework like Mockito to mock MyDAO, and inject this mock into a MyService instance. Make the mock throw the same exception as the one thrown by a real MyDAO when the network goes down when its `getCities()` method is thrown, and see is MyService does the right thing:

```
MyDAO mockDAO = mock(MyDAO.class);
List<Country> countries = Arrays.asList(new Country(...));
when(mockDAO.getCountries()).thenReturn(countries);
when(mockDAO.getCities((Country) any(Country.class))).thenThrow(new NetworkIsDownException());

MyService underTest = new MyService(mockDAO);
// TODO call underTest.getRandomCityList() and check that it does what it should do.
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-portable solution could be to modify the firewall rules of the system your test is running on, e.g. on Linux using iptables, to drop the packages and thus simulate a network outage.

A more portable solution could be to wrap the URI your database is connecting to around some proxy that can simulate network outages, much like [ActiveMQ's SocketProxy](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-broker/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/util/SocketProxy.java). This only works if your API connects to your database using an URI, though.